# Can I put Applications into Dropbox? If not, is there anywhere else I can?

Tags: dropbox, cloud, web-application, cloud-storage

I am wondering if I can use Dropbox to put applications in, or if there is another 'cloud' that I can use. This would make transferring applications from computer to computer much easier.

Comment: You can put applications in Google Drive.

Comment: Dear Manu, is that relevant to to my question here?  http://superuser.com/questions/870205/auto-updater-for-windows8-build-today

Answer (score 7):

If it exists, you could use the portable version of an app, used usually for usb key. There are a lof of them [here](http://portableapps.com/)

You could also install the app on both end, and then make a symlink in dropbox, pointing to the configuration folder, if all you want is to keep them in sync.

however, this may or may not sit well for dropbox if you have a lot of read and write on your config files or databases. Also, using the app on two computers on the same dropbox at the same time will most likely result in havoc.

Answer (score 6):

Depends on the application.  Some will function well, many will not.  The listing at http://portableapps.com/apps may be of interest in selecting and setting up apps in a Dropbox.

Answer (score 3):

You can put any files you like into Dropbox, provided you follow the ToS.

Comment: Many windows apps do not run without being "installed".  To get around this you may need to install the app on the second (or later) machines into the dropbox folder while dropbox is not running.  Then delete the files on that machine and allow dropbox to sync it from the master.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Liberkey](http://www.liberkey.com/) inside my dropbox, which gives me all the apps I need, and keeps them updated!

This is what it looks like:

[image: Here's what it looks like]

It keeps apps updated, which is a really neat feature:

[image]

It also has file association options, so that you can set windows to use liberkey apps by default rather than it's regular ones. This means you don't really need to install any additional apps on your system apart from some anti virus (Microsoft Security essentials is what I use). Although the image below shows how detailed you can be - there is also just a simply file associations on/off button!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I will add that I put a lot of applications in dropbox and for the most part it works great as long as it's nothing too complicated. Applications that try to autoupdate from the Internet can cause problems though. For applications that require installation in Windows I usually install it, copy the folder from Program Files into Dropbox and then uninstall the application. This works fine for maybe 80% of applications. Alternatively you could install it and create a symlink in Dropbox which should enable automatic updates to work, as long as they are only installed on the original machine. Of course portable apps all work great in Dropbox where that is an option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can place them in dropbox. But the catch is you either need to download the app from a browser then find them in your downloads folder using a file explorer then place it in dropbox, or you could also use a file manager that allows you to share apps these file managers are extremely hard to come across. There is one on android 4.0.1 (androids with google framework). Have fun sharing your apps!